# Convert Future<bool> to bool in flutter to check if database exists or not

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I need to convert `Future <bool>` to `bool`. I know it can be done with `then` and `await` but how?

```
class MyHomeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    bool isLogin;
    checkDatabase().then((onValue){
      isLogin = onValue;
    });

    if(isLogin) return HomePageScreen();
    if(!isLogin) return SignInScreen();
  }

  Future<bool> checkDatabase() async{
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = directory.path + 'koca.db';
    return databaseExists(path);
  }
}
```

Comment: your if condition are going to be called before your checkdatabase() will finish its execution. Put them inside the "then" condition.
Otherwise remove the then condition and just put an await before your check database like isLogin = await checkDatabase();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) :

```dart
class MyHomeApp extends StatelessWidget {

  Future<bool> get checkDatabase async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = directory.path + 'koca.db';
    return databaseExists(path);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
     FutureBuilder(
        future: checkDatabase,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (snapshot.data) {
                return HomePageScreen();
              } else {
                return SignInScreen();
              }
            }
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        },
      );
}
```